# Can't remove a line from the code?

Tags: java

The application is a number guessing game my problem is when the user get the random number right, it ask the user would you like to continue if he types in "y" it creates a new random number and asks the user to guess it. it then should ask the user "enter a number". instead i get

"too high" (or "too low")
"enter the number"

ex output:
Enter the Number:
2
Correct you've got it! The Number Was 2
You got it in 2 tries.
Would you like to play again (y/n):
y
Too low! Try again.
Enter the Number:

how do i get it to just as the question without printing the "too high" or "too low" which is suppose to be determined after he enter a number???

ps. I tried many ways but am stuck:(

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out
            .println("Welcome to the gussing game, Try to guess the number am thinking of to win!");
    System.out
            .println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
    System.out.println();

    System.out
            .println("Am thinking of a number between 0 and 10. Try to guess it.");
    System.out.println();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = "y";

    double rightNum = Math.random() * 10;
    int randomNum = (int) rightNum; // convert the random number to int
    int tries = 0;

    while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {

        System.out.println("Enter the Number:");
        int guess = sc.nextInt();
        tries++;

        if (guess == randomNum) {
            System.out.println("Correct you've got it! The Number Was "
                    + randomNum);
            System.out.println("You got it in " + tries + " tries.");
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again (y/n):");
            choice = sc.next();

            if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
            // reset the random number

            {
                rightNum = Math.random() * 10;
                randomNum = (int) rightNum;
                tries = 0;

            }
        }

        if (guess > randomNum + 10) {
            System.out.println("Way to high! Try again.");
        } else if (guess < randomNum) {
            System.out.println("Too low! Try again.");
        } else if (guess > randomNum && guess <= randomNum + 10) {
            System.out.println("Too high! Try again.");
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: come on dude! Take 5min to sort this out by yourself, you'll learn a lot more than just taking the answer from here. What about you learn how you can step into your code using your debugger? Then you'll see where your program goes wrong, it's pretty obvious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
else if (guess > randomNum + 10)
{
    System.out.println("Way to high! Try again.");
}
```

You missed the else out.

Comment: ya but, doesn't really solve my issue

Comment: @user1852564 How so? Works fine for me

Comment: it does. Otherwise if guess == random, you generate a new random number, but guess still has a value from before and that results in it falling into one of the if conditions that follow.

Comment: ya it does solve my issue sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
{
    rightNum = Math.random() * 10;
    randomNum = (int) rightNum;
    tries = 0;
}
```

to

```
{
    rightNum = Math.random() * 10;
    randomNum = (int) rightNum;
    tries = 0;
    continue; /* this goes back to while loop */
}
```